# MySql resets user password after restarting mysql server

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Well, actually it is mariadb, but to start its client, I need to enter "mysql" in command line.

Anyway, after entering

```
mysql  --user=root
```

Note, that at this time "root" doesn't have a password, so I successfully login and then:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('my_pass');
```

And it works, from now on I have to use "my_pass" to login.

But then I do:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

And from now on, root's password is again reseted to "no password at all".

And again, to login I can't give any password.

Googling this doesn't help, because most articles are about "how to reset user password" :)

Comment: Did you run this query via the root user?

Comment: Yes, first I login as root to mysql(mariadb), then I restart the mysql/mariadb service as sudo. Is there another way?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I forgot to call you.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes somebody suggested to do `flush privileges` and now I have error: "Incorrect information in file: './mysql/tables_priv.frm' "

Comment: @PhiterFernandes thanks for your post, but I have finally managed to solve my problem - I restored db dump, and then `flush privileges` worked just fine :)

Comment: Yeah the flush privileges would actually set the password and make it fixed. Forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I managed to solve my problem - if anybody's interested you have to do:

```
flush privileges
```

After changing passwords.

Answer (score 0):

I am using MacBook M2, I just uninstalled the MySQL server and then it works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).